S3 : How can I retrieve that previous version from S3
In S3 I have enabled the versioning on my bucket which holds the following file
File.txt version 1  -------------- latest
File.txt version 2
File.txt version 3
File.txt version 4

Can I delete File.txt version 1 and it will make version 2 the latest.
How I can I retrieve version 2 of the file. I am not interested in version 1. The file is not available on any other location so I cannot upload it.

If you are using the AWS Management Console then simply navigate to the S3 object and there will be a Versions tab where you can interact directly with specific versions of that S3 object (Download, Delete, etc). This tab only appears if you've turned on versioning on the S3 bucket, which you already indicated that you have. You can also enable the Show versions option in the list of S3 objects, which is required to see deleted objects.
To answer your question, yes, you can delete the latest version to restore an older version to once again be the latest version. I just want to note that S3 does not number versions sequentially, the Version ID will be a longer string with random characters and numbers.
If you are using the AWS CLI then use the --version argument with the version ID.
If you are using the S3 API directly then use the versionId request header.
